# Differential learning Rates - Keras

Tags: keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I was reading an article called [Differential Learning Rates](https://blog.slavv.com/differential-learning-rates-59eff5209a4f) on Medium and was wondering if this could be applied in Keras. I was able to find this technique implemented in pytorch. Is this possible to implement in Keras? Is there any example code that someone could provide?

Comment: This is not available out of the box in Keras. You'll find some discussion about learning rate multipliers on github, such as here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/3004

Comment: You'll also find comments by people who implemented it themselves. Maybe you can have a look at their implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from `Tensorflow 2.4`, there is an argument in  `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer`: `gradient_transformers`. It is a list of functions that take and return a list of pairs `[(gradient, Variable), ...]`. You can implement differential learning rates as transformations that decrease learning rates depending on a weight position in the network via this parameter.